# Can't avoid a div step on another div

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is the problem [site](http://newsodyssey-teambeta.rhcloud.com/casestudy1).

Let me explain in case I will solve it, so everyone can know about it.

I have two divs with the following html code

```
<div id="dataview" class="data-views" style="width:100%; height:580px; padding:0; border:solid; margin-bottom:10px;">
    <div class="row-fluid">
       <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="timeline"></div>
                        &nbsp;
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
             <div id="map" class="map"></div>
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

The two divs I am talking about are the `"col-md-8"` and `"col-md-4"`

If you try to resize the window, then the second div will move on the bottom of the first one, but it covers everything else behind it. I try to play with css, but without a success. Any suggestion?

**Edit:**
Screenshots from the problem
How it is on full window: [screen1](http://awesomescreenshot.com/0bd1w2gmd3)
How it is after resize: [screen2](http://awesomescreenshot.com/0811w2gtb0)

**Edit 2:** I think something as a sollution but it is to complicated for me. Maybe someone could help. If the size of the screen is less than col-md-8 (so the second div will move to the bottom), I will change the height of the div (data-views) to 580+(height of map).

I tried this:

```
<script>
$(window).resize(resizemap);
    function resizemap() {
        var winWidth = $(window).width();
        if (winWidth < 995) <--on 995px the map doesn't fit and move on the bottom.
        {
            var Hmap = $("#map").height();
            $('#dataview').css("height", 580+Hmap);

        }
    }
</script>
```

The problem is that instead of change the size of the whole div, it changes the height only of the timeline. And the map moves again.

Comment: You're using Twitter Bootstrap. It uses CSS Media Queries to apply different styles at different resolutions. When you shrink your page, at some point you're going to get a mobile-optimized page where your content is displayed in a single column. Is that your issue?

Comment: Yes. I am using Bootstrap, but I don't have a problem with different media. If you visit the link and try to make the window smaller, you will see that the map will overflow with the graph from the bottom.

Comment: It appears to be behaving as Bootstrap intends... I don't see the overflow issue, but I'm also getting an empty box at the top. Is that the issue?

Comment: Probably it is a connection issue. If you wait more, it supposed that you will see a timeline with a map in the empty box you said.

Comment: why are you using Bootstraps col-md-10 and then setting the width again with inline styles?  Also, the behiavior seems normal for bootstrap, but again you keep using bootstrap's classes and then overriding parts of it with inline styles so the behavior may be a little off.  If you want to disable responsiveness, its in the documentation: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#disable-responsive

Comment: You are right about the col-md-10. I forget it from an old code there. I will remove it asap. Also, I am including screenshots to see how I show the website.

Comment: Chrome and mozilla. Both the same problem

Comment: Chrome: Version 30.0.1599.101 m, Mozilla: 25

Comment: Can you take a screenshot of what you see when you resize your window on a very small width?

Comment: Here is a responsive test and it is exactly how I see it http://www.responsinator.com/?url=newsodyssey-teambeta.rhcloud.com%2Fcasestudy1

Answer (score 0):

I figure how to do it. Here is the result:

HTML:

```
<div id= "dataview" style = "height:590px;border:solid;">
    <div  class="data-views" style="width:100%;height:580px;padding:0;margin-bottom: 10px;">
      <div class="row-fluid">
          <div class="col-md-8">
              <div class="timeline"></div>
               &nbsp;
           </div>
           <div class="col-md-4">
               <div id="map" class="map"></div>
           </div>
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

And here is the javascript:

```
<script>
$(window).resize(resizemap);
window.onload = resizemap;
    function resizemap() {
        var winWidth = $(window).width();
        if (winWidth < 995)
        {
            var Hmap = $("#map").height();
            $('#dataview').css("height", 590+Hmap);

        }
    }
</script>
```

The only problem is that if I resize the window with the maximize button of the browser, the dataview height stay the same.